# Swipebox and wordpress loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Swipebox for Advanced Custom Fields gallery field to display the images in a lightbox. The gallery is activated via button and there are multiple galleries on one page (they are looped).

```
    <?php $i = 1;  ?>                      
<?php
    $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'objektid') );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="objektid_wrap">
                <div class="right">
                    <div class="right_content">
                        <h2><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h2>
                                                            <?php 
                    $images = get_field('gallery');
                        if( $images ): ?>
                          <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
                            <a class="thumb-link swipebox" href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" title="<?php echo $image['title']; ?>"><button>Vaata galeriid</button></a>
                          <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="left">
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                <?php } ?>
                </div>
                </div>
                <?php    if( $i == 2) {
                    echo '<div class="arrow_box"><span class="ion-chevron-down"></span></div>';
                    } else {
                    echo '';
                    }  ?>
        <?php $i++; endwhile;
             if (  $loop->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
             <?php endif;
    endif;
?>
```

Although swipebox combines all the gallery images when viewing in lightbox. The galleries start at the correct slide (in example the second gallery) but it contains all the slides, including the first ones. My idea is how can I implement a  refresh / reinitialize for swipebox when a second gallery is looped?

**EDIT:**

Swipebox seperates galleries via rel="gallery-1" etc. 
One way would be dynamically adding a rel="gallery-x" to every slide package

```
<div class="objektid_wrap">
<a class="thumb-link swipebox" rel="gallery-1"..
<a class="thumb-link swipebox" rel="gallery-1"..
</div>

<div class="objektid_wrap">
<a class="thumb-link swipebox" rel="gallery-2"..
<a class="thumb-link swipebox" rel="gallery-2"..
</div>
```

Any ideas on achieving this?

Best of wishes

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding `rel="gallery-<?php echo $i ?>"` to

```
 <a class="thumb-link swipebox" href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" title="<?php echo $image['title']; ?>"><button>Vaata galeriid</button></a>
```